# General Questions about Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

Hey guys and merry christmas!

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm still a little bit confused about some stuff:

**When do I need to create a new controller and when not?**

I want to create an app with a single searchbox and search through all of the articles. Should I create an Controller for the startpage (the searchbox) and for the search? Should I create controllers for the static pages?

**Should I use an Admin interface gem or create my own?**

The normal user should now have access to creating articles, just the admin. Should I use one of the admin interface gems or create my own?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails follows the MVC framework, controllers are classes that contain your actions, so you need to add an action for every function your website will provide.
Technically you could have all actions in one controller but that would be just terrible, so we usually create different controllers to organize your routes and code in a better way.
[Follow the Rails guide on controllers.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

For the admin interface gem, you could use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), they are both very reliable and well tested.

Comment: ActiveAdmin gem is also worth a look

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails is indeed MVC, which means that controllers connect Models to Views. So in general it is good practice to think more resource-oriented: per resource you want found/presented, you create a controller. In your case something like:

- `ArticlesController` : your main view, with the searchbox
- `PagesController` : for static pages, if you need some erb/haml
- `admin/ArticlesController`: for administration of the articles

Now, completely static pages can just as well be placed under the `public` folder, no need for a controller unless you need some dynamic info to be on the pages (e.g. a total count of articles).

With regards to your search-box: imho this is just a parameter for your index page. E.g. on the index you show the ten most recent articles, and when searching on some term, you show the relevant articles, but on the same controller and the same action.

With regards to the admin interface: yes, use gems like [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) or [active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) and it will get you started in no time at all. So definitely do that. But those gems are, of course, very general and might not suit your needs completely. It that should be the case, you can always easily revert later.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Everything is much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Merry christmas!

As Khaled suggested Rails being MVC architecture it is always good to have controllers of each page. Even though you might have a static pages for now, but latter when you are trying to make the site dynamic one, then you will be in whole lot confusion of where to add a method for a particular view page.

Generally it is better to use a gem instead of making it from scratch. 
You can look into this [link](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-bootstrap-devise-cancan.html) which teaches you how to use devise and cancan with twitter bootstrap(for views). But if you are planning to learn rails then I better recommend you to do it from scratch as you will have an idea of what is happening. You can see this [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) which does most of the task through scratch.

Enjoy Rails!!